# Laravel websockets AWS EC2 - Connection failed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-websockets

I'm using laravel-websockets and is working like a charm in my local docker machine but I can't seem to make it work when I deploy it in the AWS EC2 machine.

This is the error message I get:

```
pusher.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to 
'wss://sample.project:6001/app/b0901feacd04936e?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed:
```

These are my config files:

broadcasting.php

```
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
            ],
        ],
```

websockets.php

```
    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

I've opened 6001 port in my security group:
[image]

But I can't make it work. I've tried a lot of the fixes in other SO questions but none worked, am I missing something? In desperate need of help here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, unable to get the port to open up on EC2. Working fine on my local. Did you manage to get it @Miguel?

Comment: Hi @Grant, nah, I'm still lost. Tried everything I can think of and everything I found on SO. If by any chance you came by the solution, please let me know!

Comment: For me it had to do with my SSL certificate (specified via the .env file) just check the SSL section of the documentation. I think for Docker maybe you can turn SSL checks off and it may help?

Comment: In docker is working, problem is in AWS EC2. I'm not using any ssl certificates or checks

Comment: Try specifying `wssPort: 6001` as well as `wsPort: 6001`

Comment: Yeah tried that also :(

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your SSL settings in `config/websockets.php` should indicate they require two variables fron the `.env` file.

```
'ssl' => [
    'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),
    'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),
    'passphrase' => null,
    'verify_peer' => false,
],
```

Then over in your `.env` file, for local (in Valet) specify your test site's certs, ie:

```
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="/users/grant/.config/valet/Certificates/localsite.test.crt"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="/users/grant/.config/valet/Certificates/localsite.test.key"
```

Alternatively, if it's on your Production environment, point it to your production SSL CRT & key:

```
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="/etc/nginx/ssl/yourprodsite.com/1231342/server.crt"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="/etc/nginx/ssl/yourprodsite.com/1231342/server.key"
```

Your `bootstrap.js` (or similar) receiving JS end wouldn't really change - just ensure it matches what's in `config/broadcasting.php`:

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'yoursite-pusher-key',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

Config counterpart `config/broadcasting.php` inside of the `connections` array:

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => 'yoursite-pusher-key',
    'secret' => 'yoursite-secret',
    'app_id' => 'yoursite',
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'main-cluster',
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ]
    ],
],
```

Personally I could not get my setup to work without SSL & had to provide the SSL certificates accurately. Don't forget to use `valet secure` locally, if using Valet.

You can [have a look here](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl) for more info regarding SSL.

Once you serve the Websockets using `php artisan websockets:serve` it's OK if it seems like it's stalling, navigate over to the frontend & hard refresh (CMD+SHIFT+R) or Win (CTRL+F5) and hopefully the connection will be established.

Ensure you are using latest libraries and if you have set up your JavaScript init scripts inside of a bootstrap you may need to run `npm run dev` or similar to compile assets.

Comment: This is the setup that I used in my local setup with self signed certificate. However when I upload to my test server with AWS Certificate Manager that handles the SSL setup, this is no longer applicable since there is no ssl cert and private key in the server.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth - ah yeah, maybe try changing the scheme to 'http' instead on production? If that works you could add an env check for local/production & change the schema that way. Not sure 'coz I just generally use SSLs all the time on prod.